# I am Using the Aautocomplete(basically select) to create a new row in datagrid .Using the Aautocomplete causes the site to hang . I dont know why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

import { Accordion } from '../../../../common/commonComponents';
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import '../index.scss';
import { AGridColDef } from 'views/pages/manage/common/data-grid/ADataGridColDef';
;
import { AiOutlineEye } from "react-icons/ai";
import AButton from 'views/pages/manage/common/form-fields-mui/AButton'

import AAutoComplete from 'views/pages/manage/common/form-fields-mui/AAutoComplete';
import {  dummyDropDown2, selectStyles,options } from './common';


const OtherChargeList = ({isOpen,setIsOpen}) => {
    const [checkboxdata, setCheckboxdata] = useState({});

    
    const [editRowsModel, setEditRowsModel] = useState({});
    const rows = [
      {
        "id":1,
         "chargeTypeId" : 456,
         "courseId" :"72912",
         "quantity" : 1,
         "basePrice" :200.00,
         "taxes" :30.00,
         "netPayableAmount" :230.00,
         "psid" : "43762378443344",
         "applicationId" :"638483",
         "waveOffAmount" :50.00,
         "finalPayable" : 180.00,
         "paymentStatus" : "Approved"
       }
       ]
```

this is just to have some value appear in the datagrid

```
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(rows);
    
    const formHandler = (value, key, rowId) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(value) + " " + key + " " + rowId)
      setRowData(prev =>
        prev.map(row =>
          row.id === rowId
            ? { ...row, [key]: value.value} 
            : row
        )
      );
  
      
    }
```

This form handler is called to change the state when some value is selected in Aautocomplete(basically select)

```
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    const newId = 4

    // Create new row with default values
    const newRow = {
      id: newId,
      chargeTypeId: '',
      courseId: '',
      quantity: '',
      basePrice: '',
      taxes: '',
      netPayableAmount: '',
      psid: '',
      applicationId: '',
      waveOffAmount: '',
      finalPayable: '',
      paymentStatus: '',
      // isEditing: true,
     
    };
  
    setRowData([newRow, ...rowData]);
    setEditRowsModel({ [newId]: { chargeTypeId: {} , courseId: {} , quantity :{} }}); 
  };
       const chargeTypeIdMapping = {
        456: 'Misc. course',
        457: 'Type 2',
    458: 'Type 3',
  }
  const cellContainerStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    padding: '8px 12px'
  }    
  
    
     
      
 
    const columns = [    
          
        new AGridColDef('courseId', 'Course').setMinWidth(100).editable(true)
        .renderCellComponent(params => <div>{params.value}</div>)
        .renderEditCellComponent((params) => (
          <div style={cellContainerStyle}>
            <AAutoComplete
              isMulti={false}
              items={dummyDropDown2}
              currentValue={params?.row?.courseId}
              style={selectStyles}
              handleChange={value => formHandler(value, 'courseId', params?.row?.id)}
            />
          </div>
        )),



        new AGridColDef('quantity', 'Quantity').setMinWidth(100).editable(true)
        .renderCellComponent(params => <div>{params.value}</div>)
        .renderEditCellComponent((params) => {
          
          const currentValueObj = params?.row?.quantity ? options.find(option => option.value === params.row.quantity) :  { label: '1', value: '1' };]
          
      





          return (
            <div style={cellContainerStyle}>
              <AAutoComplete
                isMulti={false}
                items={options}
                currentValue={currentValueObj} // passing the object instead of the raw value
                style={selectStyles}
                handleChange={value => formHandler(value, 'quantity', params?.row?.id)}
              />
              {/* <Select
            value={currentValue}
            onChange={(event) => formHandler({ value: event.target.value, label: event.target.value }, 'quantity', params?.row?.id)}
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select> */}
            </div>
          );
        }),
        
          
      
     

    return (


        <Accordion
      isFormOpen={isOpen.detailsTab}
      title={`Other Charges`}
      key={'Other_Charges'}
       //used for creating a new row 
      rightSideButton={<AButton variant="outline" updatedStyle={{ width: "100px" ,padding :"10px"}}  onClick={handleAddClick} >Add new</AButton>} >
      


<div className="mt-3" style={{ minHeight: 300, flexGrow: 1, display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column',justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

<DataGrid
rows={rowData}
rowId={row => row.id}
columns={columns}
hideFooter
disableColumnMenu
disableColumnSelector
disableColumnReorder
disableSelectionOnClick
editRowsModel={editRowsModel}

sx={{

  padding: "0px 12px !important",
  borderRadius: "12px !important",
  
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF !important",
  "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    lineHeight: "20px",
    color: "#262626",
   
  },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader": {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    lineHeight: "20px",
    color: "#262626",
    
  },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    lineHeight: "20px",
    color: "#262626",
    fontWeight: 600,
   
  },
  '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
    outline: 'none',
  },
  '& .MuiDataGrid-cell--editing': {
    boxShadow: 'none !important',
  },

}}
/>
</div>
        </Accordion>
    )

}


    export default OtherChargeList;
```

The code creates a new row when i click on add .
The handle add puts the the new row in edit mode .
The two Aautocompletes change the value of rowData but hang and dont work properly(i guess due to state management ?)`

The dropdowns i am using :

```
export const dummyDropDown2 = [
    { label: 'A2', value: 'A2' },
    { label: 'B2', value: 'B2' },
    { label: 'C2', value: 'C2' },
  ]
 export const options = [
    { label: '1', value: '1' },
    { label: '2', value: '2' },
    { label: '3', value: '3' },
    { label: '4', value: '4' },
    { label: '5', value: '5' },
  ];
```